# Laravel 5,8. Как во время валидации обрезать http и проверить на уникальность в таблице?

Tags: laravel, валидация

1. есть таблица **stores**, в ней мы храним урлы с уже обрезанными http и https. пример: rozetka.ua , comfy.ua
2. с фронта в реквест на проверку прилетает еще не обработанный урл, с http или https . Например: http://rozetka.ua
3. как проверить сайт на уникальность в таблице **stores**? в валидации есть проверка на урл,поэтому вариант с предварительной обрезкой http не подходит.
4. так как на сайте уже настроена либа для работы с ошибками и и перехватом фронтовой и бэк валидации, то необходимо добиться условия, чтобы при валидации реквеста приходила именно ошибка как при условии unique. То-есть статус 422 и соответствующий объект ошибки.

Пока что остановился на таком варианте:

```
return [
    'url' => [
        'required',
        'string',
        'url',
        'max:255',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
           $url = parse_url($value, PHP_URL_HOST);
           if (Store::where('url', $url)->count() > 0) {
              $fail('The ' . $attribute . ' has already been taken.');
           }
        },
    ],
]
```